# Is reusing a WebGLProgram a good idea?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

Instead of creating new `WebGlProgram`'s using `gl.createProgram()` is it a good idea to keep reusing one?

I am listing the steps that I should be doing if I am to reuse one:

1. AttachShader(s): in my case I need to attach a new Fragment shader only. (Question: Can I hang on to a compiled shader?)
2. linkProgram
3. useProgram
4. getAttribLocation
5. getUniformLocation

Comment: I think your question will benefit a lot from a sample code to show what you're trying to get done. Why do you want to reuse an old program? What do you mean by hanging on to a compiled shader? Please provide some examples to demonstrate what you are trying to get done.

Comment: I'm ok with this question getting expired or I may even ask for it to be removed. The thing is once I start writing out what needs to be done then I'll have answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do? 99.9% of all GPU apps make shader programs and are done. They might make 1, they might make 5000, but they aren't ever in a position where they would even need to consider your question. So what are you really trying to do?

Those few apps that do allow you to edit shaders (shadertoy, glslsandbox, vertexshaderart, ...) either make new ones and delete old or reuse. There's no benefit to one or the other it's just a matter of style.

Yes you can hold on to shaders. You can use shaders with multiple programs. It's common to do so.

If you change a shader it won't affect a program unless/until you relink that program with `gl.linkProgram`. Anytime you call `gl.linkProgram` and it's successful all your previous uniform locations for that program are obsolete and you have to query new ones.

Comment: Thanks gman. The reason to cache a Program is the same as the reason to cache a texture, compiled shader, anything that could be improving the performance

Comment: Since then I realized that if I cached an entire program along with its linked shaders and attribute/uniform locations I have a better chance of improving the performance of my app rather than trying just to reuse a program.